# Stupid articles on launching daemons in Mac

Tags: macos, mac

I am setting up an app called Jenkins on the Mac which is a build tool.

There are many VERY helpful articles on this topic and they all involve modifying a plist to point to a newly created user.

They ALL say to start/stop using sudo

```
 sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
 sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

and they all say to create a NEW user for this purpose (how about an existing user?)

```
sudo dscl . create /Users/jenkins
sudo dscl . create /Users/jenkins PrimaryGroupID 1
sudo dscl . create /Users/jenkins UniqueID 300
sudo dscl . create /Users/jenkins UserShell /bin/bash
sudo dscl . create /Users/jenkins home /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/
sudo dscl . create /Users/jenkins NFSHomeDirectory /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/
sudo dscl . passwd /Users/jenkins
```

Now I am new to mac.  And this tells me NOTHING about:

1. how to make the app/service/daemon startup automatically when restarting the machine.
2. How does this give the user jenkins the permissions needed?
3. also I needed to login with one user to change the plist then back in with another user etc.
4. I don't even see this newly created user in /Users/jenkins at all, although each line executed ok. I don't see /Users/jenkins.
5. How will starting the machine and loggin in as admin account cause this jenkins user and the daemon to startup? I just don't get it?  Do I need to add the sudo to some startup script in the admin.

I mean really this is what I think everyone thinks of when they think of having a daemon process running.  Not constantly executing sudo this and sudo that.

I am not at all what will happen if I boot the machine and login with user jenkins. How do I make the jenkins server run no matter which user is actually logged into the machine?

Note: I executed everything from an admin account. Not root.

So I need some complete information on how to do this.

I mean what is the point of a daemon if I need to sudo load each time the machine starts?

Now my exact situation is I already have an admin user jenkinsadmin that I want to use to monitor the machine etc.  Creating this new user as above did not give me a user with admin permissions at all.  In fact executing sudo was not possible.  So how do I auto start this jenkins each time the machine boots and I login with jenkinsadmin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the Mac that Jenkins has to be startet immediately after a reboot. This is done using the so called LaunchDaemons. For more informations on LaunchDaemons and LaunchAgents have a look at [the Daemons and Services page of Apples Developer Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html).

Basically a special file that resides in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` causes the Mac to start a certain program. If the file includes `<key>RunAtLoad</key><true/>` the application will start at system boot and you will not have to manually start the process.

You do **not** need a user with administrative access rights. Just set the user as user for the process in your LauchDaemon-config-file. When the system then starts the process it will start the process as that given user. And even if you start the process manually by running `sudo launchctl` the process will finaly run as your *jenkinsadmin*-User.

Comment: And this is how you properly enable/disable run on startup: `sudo defaults write /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci RunAtLoad -bool NO`